# How to display json response in android CalendarView?

Tags: android, datetime, android-calendar, android-json, calendarview

I have a MaterialCalendarView in a android app and I have a json response like this:

```
{"Table":
[
{"userid":4,"eventname":"Aditya","eventdate":"\/Date(1479974400000-0800)\/","eventcolor":"5986FF","autoid":1011},
{"userid":4,"eventname":"dfgdgdgs","eventdate":"\/Date(1478678400000-0800)\/","eventcolor":"AD3D1F","autoid":1005},
{"userid":4,"eventname":"dfgdgdgs","eventdate":"\/Date(1478678400000-0800)\/","eventcolor":"AD3D1F","autoid":1006}
]
}
```

How to display this JSON response in my calendarView in their respective date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a fully feldged calender that scrolls horizonatlly u can use this lib: [MaterialCalenderView](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview)

use this lib to get a horrizontal calendar view .U can use decorators to show dots under dates and when u click on it , u can use a recylerview or something to list the events.

Search for decorator you can use wth dates in that library.

```
materialCalendarView.setDateTextAppearance()
materialCalendarView.addDecorator(new OpenSansDecorator(getActivity())); 
materialCalendarView.setHeaderTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearance_ProfileCalenderHeader);
materialCalendarView.setDateTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearance_ProfileCalenderCurrentDate);           
materialCalendarView.setWeekDayTextAppearance(R.style.TextAppearance_ProfileCalenderHeader);
```

styles.xml

```
<style name="TextAppearance.ProfileCalenderDate" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <!--<item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>-->
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_small</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/calender_selection_drawable</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.ProfileCalenderCurrentDate" parent="android:TextAppearance">
        <!--<item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>-->
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_size_small</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/calendar_cur_slection_drawable</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: ya I got ur idea But how to set a colors of date which have an events.

Comment: hope u got it @vicky

Comment: u can use different states to set dots or custom view(means custom text view) for each date that has events. I will provide an example if i find it in my system

Comment: updated . also check sample from that library in github. if its any help accept the answer .

Comment: How to pass the time stamp which I have received fron JSON in above code.

Comment: OpenSansDecorator(getActivity() shows error @vickey

Comment: U need to write a decorator class. check here: https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/tree/master/sample/src/main/java/com/prolificinteractive/materialcalendarview/sample/decorators

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129349/discussion-between-adi-and-vicky).

Comment: @vicky how this issue is solved?i am having same issue

Comment: @seon u can use the lib , get the dates u want to show from json and use decortaor class inside the calendar library .. please read the answer

Comment: @Vicky i am confused.how the calendar date are mapped to the JSON  coming from web.Do you have any snippet to solve this.Apart from above.

Comment: Refer the asynctask inisde this class and link your logic : https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/prolificinteractive/materialcalendarview/sample/BasicActivityDecorated.java